# How do I convert CLLocationCoordinate2D in a string value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, coordinates, mkannotationview

I want to convert the CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates of MapViewAnnotation in a string value in objective c, can anyone help me out?

Comment: `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a `struct` with two Double values. So you are looking how to convert `Double` to `NSString` and there is plenty of question about that. If you want a particular format, could you show us which one?

Comment: @Larme my expected format is - 
pickupLatLong = 30.256477,74.658954

Comment: @Harsh please put your demo code so i'm try to help you